# AttributeError: main instance has no __call__ method

Tags: python

I'm new to python.I'm getting "main instance has no **call** method" error in the below code.I'm trying to create product class objects in main class and call product class function using these objects. What is the correct way to do this to not get such error.

```
import sys
from sys import argv

class read():

    def __init__(self):
        return

    def read_function(self):
        self.file_one=open(argv[1],"r")
        self.file_two=open(argv[2],"w")
        return self.file_one,self.file_two

class product():

    def calculate(self,calc_row):
        self.calc_row=calc_row
        if "India" in calc_row[3]:
            print "In India"            
            self.tax_amt=int(calc_row[2])*5/100
            self.final_amt=self.tax_amt+int(calc_row[2])

        elif "US" in calc_row[3]:
            print "In US"            
            self.tax_amt=int(calc_row[2])*10/100
            self.final_amt=self.tax_amt+int(calc_row[2])
        else:
            print "In UK"            
            self.tax_amt=int(calc_row[2])*15/100 
            self.final_amt=self.tax_amt+int(calc_row[2])


        return self.tax_amt,self.final_amt


    def writerow(self,out_file,list,tax_am,final_am):
        self.list=data
        self.tax_am=tax_val
        self.final_am=final_val
        self.out_file=out_data
        self.string=",".join(self.list)
        self.string=self.string+","+str(self.tax_am)+","+str(self.final_am)+"\n"
        print self.string
        self.out_file.write(self.string)        

class main():
    def __init__(self):
        return

    def main_function(self):
        read_obj=read()

        self.in_data,self.out_data=read_obj.read_function()    
        self.prod_list = [product() for i in range(3)]

        for self.index,self.line in enumerate(self.in_data):
            if (self.index == 0):
                self.header=self.line
                self.header=self.header.replace("\n","")
                self.header=self.header+",Sales_Tax,Final_Price \n"
                self.out_data.write(self.header)
            else: 
                self.line.replace("/n","")
                self.data=self.line.split(",")
                self.prod=self.prod_list[index-1]
                self.tax_val,self.final_val=self.prod.calculate(self.data)
                print "Tax %d Final %d"% (self.tax_val,self.final_val)
                self.prod.writerow(self.out_data,self.data,self.tax_val,self.final_val)


product=main()
product.main_function()
write_obj=write()
print type(prod_list[0])
```

Comment: Does the error refer to any particular line?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to return anything from `__init__` and you do not need to keep empty `__init__` either (you can remove it).

Comment: self.prod_list = [product() for i in range(3)]
AttributeError: main instance has no __call__ method

Comment: `product=main()` - why do you do this? That replaces `class product():`

Comment: how do i call the main function then?

Comment: with some other object name?

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe fixed what you suggested....its not giving that error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
product = main()
```

you replace the *class* that is bound to `product` with an instance of `main`. Later, when you try to create an instance of `product`, you are actually attempting to call the instance of `main` as a function.

You need to use a different name, and the simplest way to do that is to follow the convention that user-defined class names start with uppercase letters, and all other names (excluding `CONSTANTS`) start with lowercase names.

```
import sys
from sys import argv

class Read():
    ...

class Product():
    ...        

class Main():
    ...

# This is a bad name, by the way. If you have two classes named Product
# and Main, a variable named product seems far more likely to be an
# instance of Product, not Main.
product = Main()
product.main_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

As they answered you on comments

```
class product():
```

conflicts with

```
product=main()
```

so product is not a class name anymore. Please make your classes' first letter uppercase or better take a look at PEP8

Comment: Technically, there is still a class named `product` (for now); there just isn't a *reference* to that class, since the only reference (a variable named `product`) was overwritten. It's kind of a moot point, since the class will probably be garbage collected relatively soon.

Comment: @AyushiRajguru If it is ok please vote up the answers then :)